# How I can order mysql with rate to every column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named "Articles" and wants to show in order with rating to every column
for example in this table there are 2 column with names "Likes" and "Views"
I want "Likes" Multiplied by X2 and "Views" Multiplied by X1
so If an article has 14 likes and 15 views rating for this article will be  :

```
14 X 2 = 28
15 X 1 = 15
Total : 43
```

I want show all articles by total order :)
Regards

Comment: what did you try? paste some code pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
select * , (Likes * 2 + Views * 1) as count from tablename order by count ASC
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/324f25/1)

Comment: yes , Thanks it worked as I said in previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Gather the computation in an extra column and order by this column like:

```
SELECT *, ((views)*1 + (likes)*2) AS total_count FROM Articles
ORDER BY total_count DESC
```

but this will not be fast, since you cannot put an index on this column... think about using a cache column, on which you can put an index.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ORDER BY clause to compute the rating, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Articles
ORDER BY likes*2+views DESC
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/927491/1